# Folders in Home of Ubuntu minimal install

Tags: ubuntu-minimal

Installing a minimal version of Ubuntu does not have the usual folders of Documents, Downloads, etc. in Home. Is there a way to have them just as it is in regular installs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably just missing the `xdg-user-dirs-gtk` and `xdg-user-dirs` packages. Install them and they should take care of the rest (you might have to log out and log back in to see the changes).

Comment: What would've I expected I had not installed `xdg-user-dirs-gtk`?

Comment: @arrange - Why are they even missing? XDG is a core part of FreeDesktop.org. Perhaps report a bug?

Comment: @doctormo - as Toki Tahmid writes, this is a minimal install. The package does not reverse depend on anything essential, it is also "Priority: optional", so I don't see any bug here. I don't have it on my system myself as I use different folders than default install.

Comment: Martin, I did not any GUI metapackage, and there's no reason for a GUI related package to be on a vanilla minimal install.

Comment: Looks like I'm a little late with my reply. arrange, can you answer my first comment? And would you happen to know about the black cursor in minimal install and how to get it to be the white one in normal Ubuntu? I've installed all the Ubuntu theme relate packages.

Comment: Haha, I didn't get it was a question, English is not my first language, sorry. So - from the package's description: "This extension sets the Gtk bookmark file and tracks changes of the locale to notify the user on login about changed directory names."

Comment: As for the cursor, try the `dmz-cursor-theme` package. This should add a white cursor to cursor options.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, and it's okay English wasn't my first language either, but since I was never good with my native tongue, I used English so much that I know it more than any language now and I think in English as well. Just use English on the internet like crazy, and your vocabulary will go up like there's no tomorrow - except your speaking could be lacking. Cheers!

Comment: Okay, one last question - in my last attempt of minimal install enabling numpad was not permanent and it'd get automatically disabled every session. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

It's odd that you don't have those folders... they're not taking up much space on the CD. Do you have these folders when you make a new user?

To put them back, create the folders with the right names, then go

```
gedit ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

Edit the directories by adding or changing the directories to suite, for example:

```
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
```